# Android regular expression accepting specific characters

Tags: android, regex

cant get it right, I need to accept only letters, numbers and "_" (underscore), but it not seems to work:

```
 String regex = "\\[0-9a-zA-Z\\._]";
 lastResponse = lastResponse.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

Comment: You turned the character into a sequence of chars when you escaped `[`. Since you are *replacing* / *removing* try a regex with the *negated* character class: `String regex = "[^0-9a-zA-Z._]";`. If you need to remove a dot, remove it from this pattern (you do not mention any dots in the question, but it is there in your original pattern).

Comment: If you want to accept those, then why are you replacing them? Also, the leading `\\` is for what?

Comment: You can use `"(?:.|\\W)+"`, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement,

> I need to accept only letters, numbers and "_" (underscore)

all you need to do is,

```
String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]";
lastResponse = lastResponse.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

This will replace all the characters in lastResponse except alphabets, numbers and underscore.